# How to make code dynamic for similar kind of blocks

Tags: java, java-8, vaadin, vaadin8

I am creating my web page with vaadin where I need to create same kind of blocks for different type for example need to show blocks having car details, so only car name would be different but the block design would be same with same label but different labels. I want to write generic code so that i can expand it for any car name, without adding it manually.

Attaching the code snippet which i am using where i am repeating my code for different type. Want to implement it dynamically.

```
    private Grid<PresentableGenerateInputHeaders> winTSHeaderColumnsGrid;
    private Grid<PresentableGenerateInputHeaders> fRHeaderColumnsGrid;
    private ListDataProvider<PresentableGenerateInputHeaders> listDataProvider;
    private List<PresentableGenerateInputHeaders> presentableGenerateInputHeaders = new ArrayList<>();

private void initWinTsGrid() {
    
            listDataProvider = new ListDataProvider<>(presentableGenerateInputHeaders);
            winTSHeaderColumnsGrid = new Grid<PresentableGenerateInputHeaders>(PresentableGenerateInputHeaders.class);
            winTSHeaderColumnsGrid.setDataProvider(listDataProvider);
            winTSHeaderColumnsGrid.setCaption(i18n.get("view.ruleDetails.general.csvHeaderColumns"));
            winTSHeaderColumnsGrid.setStyleName("a-units");
            winTSHeaderColumnsGrid.setWidth("450px");
            winTSHeaderColumnsGrid.setItems(addGridValues(DataSource.WIN_TS, winTSHeaderColumnsGrid));
            winTSHeaderColumnsGrid.getEditor().setEnabled(true);
            winTSHeaderColumnsGrid.setColumnOrder("header", "count");
            winTSHeaderColumnsGrid.sort("header");
            winTSHeaderColumnsGrid.getEditor().addSaveListener((EditorSaveEvent<PresentableGenerateInputHeaders> event) -> {
                event.getGrid().select(event.getBean());
                selectedGapFillingCountWINTS.add(event.getBean());
            });
        }
    
        private void initFRGrid() {
    
            listDataProvider = new ListDataProvider<>(presentableGenerateInputHeaders);
            fRHeaderColumnsGrid = new Grid<PresentableGenerateInputHeaders>(PresentableGenerateInputHeaders.class);
            fRHeaderColumnsGrid.setDataProvider(listDataProvider);
            fRHeaderColumnsGrid.setCaption(i18n.get("view.ruleDetails.general.csvHeaderColumns"));
            fRHeaderColumnsGrid.setStyleName("a-units");
            fRHeaderColumnsGrid.setWidth("450px");
            fRHeaderColumnsGrid.setItems(addGridValues(DataSource.FR, fRHeaderColumnsGrid));
            fRHeaderColumnsGrid.getEditor().setEnabled(true);
            fRHeaderColumnsGrid.setColumnOrder("header", "count");
            fRHeaderColumnsGrid.sort("header");
            fRHeaderColumnsGrid.getEditor().addSaveListener((EditorSaveEvent<PresentableGenerateInputHeaders> event) -> {
                event.getGrid().select(event.getBean());
                selectedGapFillingCountFR.add(event.getBean());
            });
        }
```

Comment: I am not really sure how this is Vaadin related.  Can we assume, you
have tried writing a function that combines the common code and is
parameterized to accept the differences and it failed somehow? Please
add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors, stacktraces,
logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can change methods to be more generic by identifying all the parts you don't want to keep static, and moving those to be populated by method parameters instead. I.e. instead of

```
private void myMethod() {
   grid.setCaption("myCaption");
}
```

you would write

```
private void myMethod(String caption) {
   grid.setCaption(caption);
}
```

and then call it

```
myMethod("myCaption");
```

If you need to be outside of the whole class to be able to determine what the real values are, you can for example make the method public or pass on the necessary values in the class constructor.

```
public MyClass(String gridCaption) {
   myMethod(gridCaption);
}
```

If there are a lot of values you need to set dynamically, you might consider using an object that contains all the necessary values instead.

```
public void myMethod(MyPojo pojo) {
    grid.setCaption(pojo.getGridCaption());
}
```

In your example it looks like the generic values you want to pass are `DataSource dataSource` and whatever type of collection `selectedGapFillingCountWINTS` and `selectedGapFillingCountFR` happen to be, and the method should probably return the grid rather than set it directly to a class variable.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer but i don't want to have multiple class variables for multiple data sources. I want to write in a very generic way so that I can add any data source without changing much in the class.

Comment: You don't have to have any class variables if you don't want to, you just need to pass them as method parameters instead.